# Dealing with "Cannot GET" error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want the following response to be outputted using node.js, but I got the "cannot GET" error, any help on how to fix it.

```
app.get('/Resturants',function (request,response){
response.send("This return the list of resturants in kumasi")};
```

Comment: what is the url you accessed ?

Comment: "Resturants" should probably be spelled "Restaurants" and you seem to be missing a closing parentheses before the semicolon. When you fix those problems and restart the server, do you still run into the same problem?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming this is Express? If so, you should add the express tag so the experts can find your question easier.

Comment: provide a screenshot